# How to support iOS 7 with XCode 6.4 iOS 8.4 SDK?

Tags: ios7, ios8.4, xcode6.4

My deployment target is 6.0, after installation is it greying out app icon on iOS 7 and below devices. Build installs fine on iOS 8 devices.

Thanks,
VP